# Amazon cognito - how do I get the user ID for permitting S3 access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using developer authenticated AWS cognito.

I want users to be able to create files under their own folders in S3.

I can do this using this policy variable:

${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}

EXCEPT it's not my developer issued userid!  It is Amazon's userid which is a long string of characters.  Not what I want as foldernames in S3.

I can't find how to get the correct policy variable to use in the policy that gives access to S3.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the developer identifier is not exposed to an IAM policy, only the identity id can currently be used for that. The LookupDeveloperIdentity API could be used to get the identity id associated with your developer identifier to name the S3 folder, though.